# Can I install Debian with encrypted /boot?

Tags: debian, boot, luks, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

Is there a way to install Debian with full disk encryption, including /boot ? Or the only way is to install Debian and encrypt all without /boot and then encrypt /boot using this guide ?

Comment: Why do you want to stop people reading your `/boot`? It is already published on the public internet. What are you trying to protect? As an attacker I can just replace it, I don't need to read it.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor because on debian website it says So called “full disk encryption” is often a misnomer, because there is typically a separate plaintext partition holding /boot meaning is better to use full disk encryption. Isn't is better to use /boot encryption ?

Comment: Yes it does. But what are you trying to protect your machine from? Protect you data by encrypting it. Protect your machine by locking it to something, by locking it in something, but not with encryption. If you leave your computer on a train, I take it, and then return it to you, and then you log in (and then latter remove it from the Faraday cage), then I have your data.

Comment: You can try to get full encryption (including `/boot`) of Ubuntu according to the following link: [Manual Full System Encryption has been updated and simplified](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2399092). But I don't think that recipe works for Debian.

Comment: The question is how not why. Either it's possible or not possible. Looking for the answer with some important use case but no helpful answer from the comment (except the last one)